# Horizontal menu dropdown items hidden behind next cell text

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

I am attempting to create webpages with horizontal menu buttons, some of which have dropdowns.  The dropdowns will overlap the next cell when hovered.  The webpage works in Chrome, Foxfire, and IE10+.  The dropdown DOES NOT work in IE9 and lower.
In IE9, the dropdown will display if there is no text in the next cell below the dropdown.  If there is text, the dropdown does not display.
URL =  http://www.arcolaalumni.org/Index_new.htm

CSS 'horiznavbar5a.css' that relates to the Horizontal Navigation Bar:

```
body 
{
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #800080;
}
p 
{
    font-family: "Calibri", sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #800080;
}   
ul#horiznav 
{       
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 30px
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 400px;  
    display: inline-table;
}
#horiznav ul 
{
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 30px
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;  
    display: inline-table;
}

#horiznav li 
{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

#horiznav li a 
{
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px 2px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    background: #5006be;
}

#horiznav li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #b387f4;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}

#horiznav li ul 
{
    display:none;  
    position:absolute;  
    left: 0;  /*...align the left edge with the left edge of the parent li...*/
    top: 22px;  /*...and 22px down from the top - 20px height + 2px for the border*/
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;  
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
}

#horiznav li:hover ul 
{
    display:block; /*display the ul when the parent li is hovered*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

#horiznav li ul a 
{
    background-color:#5006be;
}
```

Comment: please provide a code snippet or jsfiddle with just minimal code that replicates the problem. Thanks

Comment: We also prefer to see the actual code here.  External link are _supplemental_ to code posted here.